# Easiest way to split string into Key / value

Tags: javascript, regex

What's the best way to extract the key and value from a string like this:

```
var myString = 'A1234=B1234';
```

I originally had something like this:

```
myString.split('=');
```

And that works fine, BUT an equal (=) sign could be used as a key or value within the string plus the string could have quotes, like this:

```
var myString = '"A123=1=2=3=4"="B1234"';
```

The string could also only have one pair of quotes and spaces:

```
var myString = ' "A123=1=2=3=4" = B1234 ';
```

I'm not very good at regular expressions but I'm guessing that's the way forward?

What I want to end up with is two variables, key and value, in the case above, the key variable would end up being *A123=1=2=3=4* and the value variable would be *B1234*.

If there is no value present, for example if this were the original string:

```
var myString = 'A1234';
```

Then I would want the key variable to be 'A1234' and for the value variable to be null or false - or something I can test against.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to allow = as a valid character in either the key or the value?

Comment: Loosely related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328387/regex-to-replace-all-n-in-a-string-but-no-those-inside-code-code-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've tended to do in config files is ensure that there's **no** possibility that the separator character can get into either the key or value.

Sometimes that's easy if you can just say "no '=' characters allowed" but I've had to resort to encoding those characters in some places.

I generally hex them up so that if you wanted a '=' character, you would have to put in %3d (and %25 for the '%' character so you don't think it's a hex-starter character). You can also use %xx for any character but it's only **required** for those two.

That way you can check the line to ensure it has one and only one '=' character then post-process the key and value to turn the hex'ed characters back into real ones.

Comment: You're right - it's too much of a hastle to cater to the people who will want to use the equal sign. I ended up just using the split thing - I might come up with some unicode thing in the future. Thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 4):

can't help with a one-liner, but I'll suggest the naive way:

```
var inQuote = false;
for(i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
   if (str.charAt(i) == '"') {
      inQuote = !inQuote;
   }
   if (!inQuote && str.charAt(i)=='=') {
      key = str.slice(0,i);
      value = str.slice(i+1);
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget backslashes for escaping enclosed quotes! But this is pretty much the same approach I'd take. Regular expressions are not the right tool here. This is a job for a parser.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've saved it for the future - for this particular issue I'm gonna just ignore those 'equal' signs and thinking about it, there is no real need for the user to have the opportunity to include quotes. - I'll strip them at user entry instead.

Comment: In Internet Explorer you can't use str[x], but can use str.charCode(x)

Comment: Damn stupid browser incompatibilities :-) - this is why I love jQuery with a passion.

Comment: good call @some... I actually asked a SO question about IE and str[x] before, but I keep forgetting :)

Answer (score 3):

```
/^(\"[^"]*\"|.*?)=(\"[^"]*\"|.*?)$/
```

Comment: Put a $ at the end of that, otherwise the lazy matcher lives up to its name and matches nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If we make a rule that all keys with equal signs need to be embedded within quotes, then this works well (I can't imagine any good reason for letting escaped quotes within a key.)

```
/ ^               # Beginning of line
  \s*             # Any number of spaces
  ( " ( [^"]+) "  # A quote followed by any number of non-quotes, 
                  # and a closing quote
  | [^=]*         # OR any number of not equals signs 
    [^ =]         # and at least one character that is not a equal or a space
  )               
  \s*             # any number of spaces between the key and the operator
  =               # the assignment operator
  \s*             # Any number of spaces 
  (.*?\S)         # Then any number of any characters, stopping at the last non-space
  \s*             # Before spaces and...
  $               # The end of line.
```

/

Now in Java, properties files (they break at the first ':' or '=', though) you can have multiple lines in a property by putting '\' at the end of the line, so it would be a little trickier.