# C# Regex replace in string only outside tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string, which represents part of xml.

```
string text ="word foo<tag foo='a' />another word "
```

and I need to replace particular words in this string. So I used this code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\b" + co + "\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
return regex.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(subZvyrazniStr));
static string     subZvyrazniStr(Match m)
    {
        return "<FtxFraze>" + m.ToString() + "</FtxFraze>";
    }
```

But the problem of my code is, that it also replaces string inside tags, which i don't want to. So what should I add, to replace words only outside tags?

Ex.: when I set variable co to "foo" I want to return `"word <FtxFraze>foo</FtxFraze><tag foo='a' />another word"`

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't try to parse or modify XML with Regexes if the XML structure is relevant. [See this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1633117) Use an XML parser instead. Then you can apply the Regex code to text nodes only.

Comment: I know but In this case, I have a lot of nodes and I don't know the exact structure, so I think it's faster and easier to do this with regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple trick like this may suffice in some cases if you are not that picky:

```
\bfoo\b(?![^<>]*>)
```

Comment: the `[^<>]` should be `[^<]`..no need of `>`

Comment: Can you please explain this regex?

Comment: @Anirudha, the `>` helps the regex engine find the match faster, otherwise it needs to backtrack. (Altho that depends on the engine and how optimized it is.)

Comment: @david, `(?![^<>]*>)` is a negative lookahead, it fails the match if the word is followed by a `>`, without a `<` between, thus suggesting that the word is inside an open tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want

```
(?<!\<[\w\s]*?)\bfoo\b(?![\w\s]*?>)
```

works [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

I had answered a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305182/parse-commas-not-surrounded-by-brackets/12305883#12305883)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b" + rep + @".*?(?=\<)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This matches `"foo <tag>bar"` in `"foo <tag>bar</tag>"` and `"football"` in `"<tag>football</tag>"`. The reluctant quantifier, `.*?`, is too weak for this job; you need to actively exclude the `<` like @Qtax did. And you have to do that inside the lookahead, so you only consume the word foo.