# RegEX expression for images

Tags: php, regex

How can I modify the following Regex to be **NOT** executed if the `<img>` tag is within `<script>` tags (respectively `<script language="...">`, meaning `<script*>`)

**Code:**

```
function seo_friendly_images($content) {

return preg_replace_callback('/<img[^>]+/', 'seo_friendly_images_process', $content);

}

add_filter('the_content', 'seo_friendly_images', 100);
```

Comment: [Have you tried an HTML parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/476)

Comment: I was looking into it, is this conditional going the right way if (stripos($content, '<script') !== false) {

Comment: [You shouldn't be using regex for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) However, [your problem is similar to this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554005/c-sharp-regex-replace-in-string-only-outside-tags)

Answer (score 1):

This depends a bit on the language you're using. Some languages support look ahead or look behind (e.g. match foo only when followed by bar or match bar only when preceeded by foo).

This looks like php to me which reports to have look ahead support (http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

Try using a regex like

```
    /<script[^>]+>(?=<img)/ or /<script[^>]+>(?!<img)/
```

?= indicates a positive look ahead and ?! indicates a negative look ahead.
Positive look ahead meaning "Foo is followed by Bar", Negative look ahead meaning "Foo is not followed by Bar".

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try this:

```
return preg_replace_callback('<img[^<]+?>', 'seo_friendly_images_process', $content);
```

Not tested thouogh.