# MatchEvaluator to wrap text insensitive to case, EXCEPT when text is within an image HTML tag (but NOT ignoring ALL tags)

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace, tags

I have an HTML body of text that is created in my CMS. I have a custom method to highlight search terms in the text, so that when a user navigates to the page from the search results, all occurrences of the search term are highlighted. I have this set up to be case insensitive, so that the matching text will be highlighted regardless of capitalization, and the result will retain the original capitalization:

```
var regex = new Regex(searchTerm, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(match => Evaluators.Wrap(match, textToFormat, "<span class='highlight'>{0}</span>"));
var highlightedText = regex.Replace(textToFormat, evaluator);
```

This results in the following (say a user has searched for "text"):

```
"This is some text!" -> "This is some <span class='highlight'>text</span>!"
```

However I've discovered an issue that occurs when the HTML body contains image tags, and the image URL contains the search term. This is breaking the images on the page.

```
"This is some text: <img src='/images/text.png'/>" ->  "This is some <span class='highlight'>text</span>: <img src='/images/<span class='highlight'>text</span>.png'/>"
```

Is there a way that I can ignore text that is inside an image tag, while still wrapping all other text and maintaining capitalization?

This is NOT the same as [C# Regex replace in string only outside tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554005/c-sharp-regex-replace-in-string-only-outside-tags), because there's plenty of text within `<p>` and `<span>` tags that I DO need to replace. I only need to ignore text inside `<img>` and `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
var regex = new Regex($@"(<(?:img|a)(?:\s[^>]*>)?)|{Regex.Escape(searchTerm)}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var highlightedText = regex.Replace(textToFormat, m =>
     m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : $"<span class='highlight'>{m.Value}</span>");
# => This is some <span class='highlight'>Text</span>: <a href='/text.html'><img src='/images/text.png'/></a>
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/9dPoQA)

The regex is

```
(<(?:img|a)(?:\s[^>]*>)?)|text
```

See [its demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3C%28%3F%3Aimg%7Ca%29%28%3F%3A%5Cs%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E%29%3F%29%7Ctext&i=This%20is%20some%20Text%3A%20%3Ca%20href%3D%27%2Ftext.html%27%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%27%2Fimages%2Ftext.png%27%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E&o=i). It matches:

- `(<(?:img|a)(?:\s[^>]*>)?)` - Capturing group 1: `<`, `img` or `a`, then an optional sequence of a whitespace and then any 0+ chars other than `>` and then a `>` char
- `|` - or
- `text` - some string.

If Group 1 is matched, replace with the Group 1 value (i.e. restore the `<a>` or `<img>` tags), else wrap the match with a span tag.

Do not forget to escape your `searchTerm` to make sure it won't cause issues if it contains special characters. To search for a whole word, consider using unambiguous word boundaries, `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)`, `new Regex($@"(<(?:img|a)(?:\s[^>]*>)?)|(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(searchTerm)}(?!\w)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`.