# PHP preg_split delimiter pattern, split at character chain

Tags: php, design-patterns, delimiter, preg-split

With the following string:

```
$str = '["one","two"],a,["three","four"],a,,a,["five","six"]';

preg_split( delimiter pattern, $str );
```

How would I have to set up the **delimiter pattern** to obtain this result:

```
$arr[0] = '["one","two"]';
$arr[1] = '["three","four"]';
$arr[2] = '["five","six"]';
```

In other words, is there a way to split at the pattern ',a,' AND ',a,,a,' BUT check for ',a,,a,' first because ',a,' is a sub string of ',a,,a,'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you ok with using preg_match instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split string by ',' unless ',' is within brackets using Regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732029/how-to-split-string-by-unless-is-within-brackets-using-regex) or [PHP: split string on comma, but NOT when between braces or quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15233953)

Comment: Yes I would be fine with using preq_match too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can only be `,a,` and `,a,,a,`, then this should be enough:

```
preg_split("/(,a,)+/", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're actually trying to do is separate out the square bracketed parts. You could do that like so:

```
$arr = preg_split("/(?<=\])[^[]*(?=\[)/",$str);
```

Comment: I tested your pattern, should be changed to: `/(?<=\])[^[]*(?=\[)/`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
$result = array();

preg_match_all("/(\[[^\]]*\])/", '["one","two"],a,["three","four"],a,,a,["five","six"]', $result);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true);
```

It will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ["one","two"]
            [1] => ["three","four"]
            [2] => ["five","six"]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ["one","two"]
            [1] => ["three","four"]
            [2] => ["five","six"]
        )
)
```